# Downloaded octet-stream then encoding as pdf; can't get line endings worked out

Tags: pdf, encoding, httpresponse, fiddler

Tools that I'm using for this:

`Chrome
 Notepad++
 Sublime Text 3
 Fiddler
 WinMerge
 Adobe Acrobat Reader X`

### Synopsis

I have downloaded a pdf twice, once through Chrome as an experimental control; once again through a raw `/GET` request via Fiddler which returns me an octet-stream. To this point, I can save the octet-stream as pdf and I can get the proper page count and some of the page headers and numbers, but very little of the body content is loading.  When I open my file in Adobe Reader X, I get an error that it

> Cannot extract the embedded font 'LFIDTH+ArialMT'. Some characters may not display or print correctly

and I cannot work through why it can be extracted from the 'true' pdf but cannot from the one I am saving.

### Details

As for my manual pull of the file, I have provided

`Accept: application/pdf, application/x-pdf, application/x-gzpdf, application/x-bzpdf`

The server sent me back an `aplication/octet-stream` with an attachment Disposition.

So to recap:

1. Valid Foo.pdf sitting on my hard drive
2. HTTP Response with an octet-stream version of same file, in UTF-8 encoding (I assume)

---

### Here is what I know:

I pulled the Message Body of the response from the server and dropped it to file.  I then ran a WinMerge comparison of it against the contents of the pdf and every line mismatched on line endings.  I re-encoded the EOLs for Unix and the diff shrank to ~1k lines out of 160k. A close inspection of the mismatch indicates that the valid pdf maintains what looks like a NUL `00` character in places whereas my octet-stream contains literal spaces.  Also, the "true" pdf is reporting `EOL: LF  1252 Mixed` through WinMerge. My "raw" pdf is reporting `1252 Unix` When I homogenize the 'true' pdf to `1252 Unix`, I get the same issue as I explained in the 'raw' one.

Is there anything I can do to get this mess of an octet-stream straightened out?

> Note that the pdf that was downloaded through Chrome is historic. I have it on my machine, but I downloaded it "sometime in the past" and the request headers used when processing that `/GET` are no longer available.  Attempting to download through the browser "now" results in an error, but an explicit GET request against the resource through Fiddler is returning the pdf as an octet-stream.

Comment: *I pulled the Message Body of the response from the server and dropped it to file.* - How did you do this? Considering your description of symptoms you seem to have done this using methods designed for handling text (which is utterly wrong, PDF essentially is a binary format, period).

Comment: Well...the message body of the response is the data (in this case, it is an octet-stream) that begins after the CRLF that follows the Header.  I "pulled" it by copying the message body and dropping it to file. I am now trying to get the encoding worked out such that it is a true pdf rather than its raw data transmitted across the wire

Comment: *a true pdf rather than its raw data* - what is the difference?

Comment: The "true pdf" came back as an application/pdf. The "raw pdf" came back as an application/octet-stream with a Content-Disposition of attachment

Comment: In essence the contents *should* be identical, independent of the mime type.

Comment: I realize that. The point is that in order to get the octet-stream to file, I copied the message body from Fiddler and it seems to have it in the clipboard as UTF-8.  The "true pdf" is reporting 1252 with Mixed line endings. I mentioned all of this in the text of my question

Comment: You should be aware that PDF, while it looks like a text file, is a binary file format and the offsets within the file count very much to the validity of the file. PDFs can be written with any standard combination of line ending disciplines (\r, \n, \r\n) and if you blindly change that with tr, you are damaging the file.

Comment: @plinth ...well aware of all of that.  This turned out to be much more of a "how do I do this through Fiddler" question than I originally thought it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well now....

In Fiddler Session,

Right click HTTP Response with the `application/octet-stream` body | Save | Response | Response Body

If `Content-Disposition: attachment;filename` has been set on the response, the File Save Dialog will be prepopulated with `filename`

Easy after you know it's there.

Comment: You can also use `File` > `Export` > `Raw Files` if you'd like to do this with a lot of HTTP responses at once.